# Looking for explanation of "His smile fair as spring, as towards him he draws you"

Tags: meaning, songs

As the title, I couldn't figured out anything by myself from this sentence

> His smile fair as spring, as towards him he draws you.

Especially "fair as spring", seems my first time to see the combination like this, I looked up "fair" in dictionary.com to see the list of meanings, this way usually can solve my question, but not this time

Can anyone give a clue about "fair as spring"? will be the best if another clue relating to second part of the sentence :P

Thank you very much

Its referenced in a game "The Witcher 3" mirror master song
btw, hearts of stone is a wonderful DLC

Comment: The definitions you have found should be included, together with a comment on which you think more or less likely to be appropriate here.

Comment: Because he is a guy, so I thought it’s wrong to express beautiful here, and he is also a businessman, made me think “fair” is means “No cheating” here, but confused with “as spring”

Comment: The simile is 'as fair as spring'. Not all that common, perhaps, but a fair number of hits on Google. These really mandate that 's/Spring' here is the season. And most of them force the 'beautiful / delightful' reading.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks, so does “as fair as moon” has same meaning? -> beautiful like the moon

Comment: 'As fair as the moon'. Yes; you might like to read [Kathryn Armstrong's](https://kathrynwarmstrong.wordpress.com/tag/what-does-it-mean-to-be-fair-as-the-moon/) commentary on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fair*, in this case, means *beautiful*:

> **fair** adjective (BEAUTIFUL)
>
> old use or literary (of a woman) beautiful:
>
> - a fair maiden

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fair)

Cambridge implies that this meaning can only be used for a woman, but I see no reason why it cannot be used for a handsome man (or his smile):

> Mourn all ye Loves, the fair Adonis dyes.

[The First Edilium of Bion English'd by the Right Honourable the Earl of Winchilsea](http://www.jimandellen.org/finch/mournall.html)

Of course, we cannot forget Shakespeare:

> The fair Ophelia!—Nymph, in thy orisons
>   Be all my sins remembered.

Shakespeare, *Hamlet*, Act 3, Scene 1

Comment: I should start reading phrases of Shakespeare